# Node.js performance- reading files once or on every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I am serving a page using Node.js and Express. Part of the data for that page is related to a directory of files.

First just a single directory read, which means that the server has to be restarted to update the directory.

```
var files;
fs.readdir(path, function (err,data)
{
   files = data;
});
app.get('/', function (req,res)
{
   res.render('index', {files: files});
});
```

And second a directory read on every request, which may affect performance.

```
app.get('/icons', function (req,res)
{
    fs.readdir(path, function (err,files)
    {
        res.render('index', {files: files});
    });
});
```

Is there a significant performance differences between these two options?

Comment: You could use something like [gaze](https://github.com/shama/gaze) to watch the directory for changes and update your in-memory list of files. That way you don't have to restart the server and you don't have to read the directory contents on every request.

Comment: The first approach has a race condition.  Use promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach trades disk IO for memory usage; the second approach trades memory usage for disk IO.

Since memory is faster than disk, the first approach is faster (unless you run out of memory).

On the other hand, the second approach will pick up changes made after the server starts.